# Как мне открыть панель для настройки какого либо из объектов, по типу pallete или atributtes в android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Как мне открыть панель для настройки какого либо из объектов, по типу pallete или atributtes в android studio, а так же сделать рамку?
[image: Мое]

[image: Как на этом фото]